# setKind() not taken into account

Tags: c++, udp, omnet++, packet, inet

I'm trying to Identify a message by using the getKind() function, I've previously defined my own DATA_KIND
for sending:

```
DataM *data = new DataM();
data ->setKind(DATA_KIND);
data ->setSrc(this->getParentModule()->getIndex());
socket.sendTo(data, destAddr, destPort);
```

for receiving which it bypasses but is received as as a UDP_I_DATA
bypasses this:

```
else if (msg->getKind() == DATA_KIND) {
    // process incoming packet;
}
```

and uses this:

```
else if (msg->getKind() == UDP_I_DATA) {
    // process incoming packet;
}
```

Please help!

I have tried adding the DATA_KIND value to the .h files and to the .cc files, I thought it was about the scope, it didn't work

Comment: What is the definition of DataM?

Comment: @kiner_shah namespace inet;
packet DataM{
    int src;
    int dest;
}

Comment: Please share a [mre].

Comment: @kiner_shah I'm using the UDPBasicAPP as foundation, I didn't change anything relevant to this except for what I've already stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `setKind()/getKind()` to carry out own information across **the whole network** in INET. Kind is a metadata that is used mainly between modules **inside** a device - to inform about the status of a packet. Therefore UDP layer always sets the value of kind for received packets (e.g.`UDP_I_DATA`, `UDP_I_ERROR`).

I suggest introducing own packet with the field that will determine the type, e.g. 1 - MY_DATA, 2 - MY_CONTROL, etc.
An example:

```
packet DataM {
  int myType;    // own type
  // other data
  int otherData;
  
}
```

Then in your code you may use:

```
// somewhere in *.h 
#define MY_DATA    1
#define MY_CONTROL 2


// in *.cc - sending 
DataM *data = new DataM();
data->setMyType(MY_DATA);

// in *.cc - receiving
DataM *data2 = dynamic_cast<DataM*>(msg);
if (data2 != nullptr) {
  if (data2->getMyType == MY_DATA) {
      // MY_DATA - do something
  }
}
```

References:

1. [OMNeT++ Simulation Manula - 6 Message Definitions](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:msg-def)
2. [TicToc Tutorial - 4.4 Defining our message class](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part4/#44-defining-our-message-class)

Comment: Do you any documentation to suggest for that purpose? as it is the first time I'm using omnet, thank you

Comment: I have extended my answer.